# IP addresses of backbone routers

Tags: data-request, internet

How would I go about finding a dataset of IP addresses of backbone routers? Looking around on Google didn't seem to help. Is this information available somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use data from [Caida (Cooperative Association for Internet Data Analysis)](http://www.caida.org/).   In particular their Macroscopic Internet Topology Data Kit (ITDK) may suite your needs.

http://www.caida.org/data/internet-topology-data-kit/

Quoting from the above page:

The ITDK contains data about connectivity and routing gathered from a large cross-section of the global Internet. This dataset is useful for studying the topology of the Internet at the router-level, among other uses.

The latest ITDK release, 2013-07, currently consists of

- two related router-level topologies,
- router-to-AS assignments,
- geographic location of each router, and
- DNS lookups of all observed IP addresses.

Comment: Wow, very comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

This image is prominent on the Wikipedia article for [Internet backbone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_backbone).
[image: Internet backbone image]

> Each line is drawn between two nodes, representing two IP addresses. This is a small look at the backbone of the Internet.

The source and raw data can be obtained from http://www.opte.org/maps/.

Unfortunately, the data is from 2005.

---

If you can tolerate the HTML, you can find long lists of T3 nodes here: http://cities.lk.net/trlist.html All of their links to world maps are dead, unfortunately.

---

Instead of finding an online list, you can put together your own using the unix command '[traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute)' and some scripting - [See here for example.](http://www.cybercon.com/backbone.html)

Comment: Thanks for your research! I think this will get me started. I wish there was more current data.

Comment: My answer isn't great, but I'm glad it will get you started.